jTidy issue with character encoding/decoding
I am using jTidy 8 to tidy html in rich text editor. Whenever I put "%7BA3" in editor, jTidy converts it to "箣". I want jTidy to keep my url containing "%7BA3" as it is.
For eg: https://example.com/%7BA3 (input) is now converted into https://example.com/箣 (actual output) I want it to be : https://example.com/%7BA3 (required output)
I tried:

appending raw_URL_raw

tidy.setFixUri(false)



Both the options didn't work in my case. Any suggestions on how to make jTidy to achieve above task?

What about https://example.com/%E7%AE%A3?

Thanks @g00se for response. 'https://example.com/%E7%AE%A3' is resulting in 'https://example.com/%E7%AE%A3'. But I want 'https://example.com/%7BA3'.

Actually your version is wrong. It should be what I posted. I suspect it's not JTidy that's doing this. And, at first glance at least, the fixUri stuff actually seems to do the reverse of what's happening to you
